Audio intermitency js
The page is exibit in a TV on a reception. When it's open we got a dialog with a button to allow the webpage to play audio. And the page refresh itself after 40 seconds.
For the most time of the day, the page is playing the sound, but sometimes, the text is updated but the sound is not heard. And it just come back after a manual refresh(F5). It seems the problem is with the browser. As the page has not user interactions, in addition tobutton to allow the sound, maybe the browser is disabling the sound?
On the manual refresh case, there was no interaction with the page, like a click, just a F5.
Currently we're using the Audio, should i try with the AudioContext?
We though the problem was with cache, so we created a auto refresh, but it wasn't enougth to resolve the problem.
i'm expecting now to find a clue about what's stopping the audio from playing
audio code:
async function playAudio(url){
    audio = new Audio(url)
    return new Promise(res => {
        audio.play()
        audio.onended = res
    })
}


Please show us the relevant code, currently I’m not at all clear what question you are asking. Is the problem that you have to wait for a user interaction to play the sound?

Have you found any information regarding this in the developer tools of the browser?

@AHaworth the currently problem is that the audio just stop playing after some time, this page just receive one user interaction at the begining of the day and it has to play the sound everytime a client is called, but after some time working it just stops. The client is updated on the screen, but the sound does not play. Even if it was working before

@AprilSummers i have not, i'm still searching for clues on this

'and the page refresh itself after 40 seconds' - I think we need to see more of the code, in particular what is this actually doing?

Really, this is a configuration problem of the browser.  I imagine you'd want to configure it to not need this user interaction at all.

@Brad yeah, that's what i want but it seems impossible with this browser rules, maybe a browser that doesnt need user interaction?

@IsraelBessa What platform are you running on this monitor?  If it's just Chrome/Chromium, you can use --autoplay-policy=no-user-gesture-required when starting the browser.

I think there’s something fundamental I’m not understanding here. What is the purpose of using JS (Promise and res) as opposed to using an HTML loop attribute?

Ah, just looked again and see ‘every time a client is called’. Are you creating a new element each time? If so where are you deleting it? We do need to see more context of how this is being used.

@AHaworth there's any difference between using it with JS and as a HTML attribute? I can only reolad the page if the audio is not playing, so that's why i'm using js. For now i'm trying to update to the AudioContext

Well, the difference might be that you are creating a new element each time, but without seeing the code you use to call that function it's impossible to tell. Is there a reason you are unable to show us more of the context-code?

Sorry I can't show the code, but I managed to solve the problem by inserting the url into the list of always-on sites in the browser

I managed to solve the problem by inserting the url into the list of always active sites in the browser
Chrome: Settings > Performance > Always keep these sites active
As the page has no user interaction, the browser was changing it's state to increase performance, and this was affecting the audio. Setting this configuration will stop the browser from change the page state.
